# DataTables show "Processing..." label when dynamically fnAddData

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a function to dynamically add data into the DataTables. Here is the function.

```
function fnClickAddRow() {
    for (i=0; i<10000; i++) {
        $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [
         giCount+".1",
         giCount+".2",
         giCount+".3",
         giCount+".4" ]
        );
    }
}
```

This function will dynamically append into my **#example** datatable, but the screen looks hanging during the manipulation, is there a way to show the loading / processing sign using the **"processing": true,**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no function to trigger display of "Processing" message through API, however there is a workaround.

You need to enable processing indicator with `bProcessing: true` (for DataTables 1.9) or `processing: true` (for DataTables 1.10).

To show processing indicator for table with id `example`:

```
$('.dataTables_processing', $('#example').closest('.dataTables_wrapper')).show();
```

To hide processing indicator for table with id `example`:

```
$('.dataTables_processing', $('#example').closest('.dataTables_wrapper')).hide();
```

Another thing worth mentioning is that for some reason processing indicator wasn't displayed until I added `setTimeout` with 100ms delay.

On the side note, for performance you need to specify `false` as a second parameter to `fnAddData()` to indicate that no re-draw is required. Once you're finished adding the rows, you can call `fnDraw()` to redraw the table, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLe8os5t/1/).

You can improve performance even further if you put the data first into an array and then call `fnAddData()` once.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLe8os5t/2/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 3):

There now appears to be a [processing() plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/processing()) that permits you to do this via API.

Once the plugin is installed, this can be invoked as (for example): `table.processing([true/false]);`