# How do I delay the processing message for DataTables

Tags: c#, jquery, datatables

I have read the [DataTables documentation](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/50748/processing-message) on the "boxed" solution of either turning off or on the processing message, by either setting it to true or false. This is my current setup:

```
"processing": true, // for show progress bar
"serverSide": true, // for process server side
```

What I want to do instead is delay this message for 1 or 2 seconds so that it only appears for tasks that take longer than 1 or 2 seconds, but this functionality doesn't exist out of the box. How do I do this?

Comment: Create your own processing message.  You can initiate it x seconds after the datatable is fetching data and then hide it when the data is returning to the datatable.

Comment: @devlincarnate right, but it would be cleaner if I could grab that processing message and add a `wait()` to it. I just dont know where to hook into it

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367233/datatables-show-processing-label-when-dynamically-fnadddata).

Comment: You could build a `setTimeout()` into the processing callback: https://datatables.net/reference/event/processing

Comment: You can also use https://datatables.net/reference/event/preInit to trigger your own processing message.